# How to setup sendSignInLinkToEmail() from Firebase in react-native?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Working on a `react-native` project using `@react-native-firebase/app` **v6** we recently integrated signing in with a "magic link" using [auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#sendSignInLinkToEmail)

We couldn't find a good example on how to setup everything in react-native and had different problems like
- `auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain` - The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project.
- `auth/unauthorized-continue-uri` - Domain not whitelisted by project

Searching for information and implementing the "magic link login" I've prepared a guide on how to have this setup in react-native

Answer (score 53):

## Firebase project configuration

Open the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

### Prepare firebase instance (Email Link sign-in)

1. open the **Auth** section.
2. On the **Sign in method** tab, enable the **Email/Password** provider. Note that email/password sign-in must be enabled to use email link sign-in.
3. In the same section, enable **Email link (passwordless sign-in)** sign-in method.
4. On the **Authorized domains** tab (just bellow)
5. Add any domains that will be used

   - For example the domain for the `url` from [ActionCodeSettings](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/actioncodesettings#url) needs to be included here

### Configuring Firebase Dynamic Links

1. For IOS - you need to have an ios app configured - Add an app or specify the following throughout the firebase console

   - Bundle ID
   - App Store ID
   - Apple Developer Team ID
2. For Android - you just need to have an Android app configured with a package name
3. Enable Firebase Dynamic Links - open the **Dynamic Links** section

   - *“Firebase Auth uses [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) when sending a link that is meant to be opened in a mobile application.
     In order to use this feature, Dynamic Links need to be configured in the Firebase Console.”*

(ios only) You can verify that your Firebase project is properly configured to use Dynamic Links in your **iOS** app by opening
the following URL: `https://your_dynamic_links_domain/apple-app-site-association`

It should show something like:

```json
{
     "applinks": {
         "apps": [],
         "details": [
             {
                 "appID": "AP_ID123.com.example.app",
                 "paths": [
                     "NOT /_/",                     "/"
                 ]
             }
         ]
     }
 }
```

## IOS Xcode project configuration for universal links

1. Open the Xcode project and go to the **Info** tab create a new URL type to be used for Dynamic Links.
2. Enter a unique value in **Identifier** field and set the **URL scheme** field to be your bundle identifier, which is the default URL scheme used by Dynamic Links.

   - [image: Info|Url Types setup]
3. In the **Capabilities** tab, enable **Associated Domains** and add the following to the Associated Domains list: `applinks:your_dynamic_links_domain`

   - (!) This should be only the domain - no https:// prefix
   - [image]

## Android

Android doesn’t need additional configuration for default or custom domains.

---

## Packages

A working react-native project setup with react-native-firebase is required, this is thoroughly covered in the library own documentation, here are the specific packages we used

- Note: using the `dynamicLinks` package can be replaced with react-native's own Linking module and the code would be almost identical

Exact packages used:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.7.1",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^6.7.1",
```

---

## Sending the link to the user email

The module provides a `sendSignInLinkToEmail` method which accepts an email and action code configuration.
Firebase sends an email with a magic link to the provided email. Following the link has different behavior depending on the action code configuration.

The example below demonstrates how you could setup such a flow within your own application:

EmailLinkSignIn.jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Alert, AsyncStorage, Button, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const EmailLinkSignIn = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput value={email} onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)} />
      <Button title="Send login link" onPress={() => sendSignInLink(email)} />
    </View>
  );
};

const BUNDLE_ID = 'com.example.ios';

const sendSignInLink = async (email) => {
  const actionCodeSettings = {
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
    url: 'https://www.example.com/magic-link',
    iOS: {
      bundleId: BUNDLE_ID,
    },
    android: {
      packageName: BUNDLE_ID,
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: '12',
    },
  };

  // Save the email for latter usage
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);

  await auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings);

  Alert.alert(`Login link sent to ${email}`);
  /* You can also show a prompt to open the user's mailbox using 'react-native-email-link'
  * await openInbox({ title: `Login link sent to ${email}`, message: 'Open my mailbox' }); */
};

export default EmailLinkSignIn;
```

We're setting `handleCodeInApp` to `true` since we want the link from the email to open our app and be handled there. How to configure and handle this is described in the next section.

The `url` parameter in this case is a fallback in case the link is opened from a desktop or another device that does not
have the app installed - they will be redirected to the provided url and it is a required parameter. It's also required to
have that url's domain whitelisted from [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) - Authentication -> Sign in method

You can find more details on the supported options here: [ActionCodeSettings](/reference/auth/actioncodesettings)

## Handling the link inside the app

Native projects needs to be configured so that the app can be launched by an universal link as described
above

You can use the built in **Linking** API from `react-native` or the **dynamicLinks** `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links` to intercept and handle the link inside your app

EmailLinkHandler.jsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

const EmailLinkHandler = () => {
  const { loading, error } = useEmailLinkEffect();

  // Show an overlay with a loading indicator while the email link is processed
  if (loading || error) {
     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Boolean(error) && <Text>{error.message}</Text>}
        {loading && <ActivityIndicator />}
      </View>
    );
  }

  // Hide otherwise. Or show some content if you are using this as a separate screen
  return null;
};

const useEmailLinkEffect = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDynamicLink = async (link) => {
      // Check and handle if the link is a email login link
      if (auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(link.url)) {
        setLoading(true);

        try {
          // use the email we saved earlier
          const email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
          await auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, link.url);

          /* You can now navigate to your initial authenticated screen
            You can also parse the `link.url` and use the `continueurl` param to go to another screen
            The `continueurl` would be the `url` passed to the action code settings */
        }
        catch (e) {
          setError(e);
        }
        finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    };

    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);

     /* When the app is not running and is launched by a magic link the `onLink`
        method won't fire, we can handle the app being launched by a magic link like this */
    dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()
      .then(link => link && handleDynamicLink(link));

    // When the component is unmounted, remove the listener
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return { error, loading };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(250,250,250,0.33)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

const App = () => (
  <View>
    <EmailLinkHandler />
    <AppScreens />
  </View>
);
```

You can use the component in the root of your app as in this example

Or you can use it as a separate screen/route - in that case the user should be redirected to it after
the `sendSignInLinkToEmail` action

Upon successful sign-in, any [`onAuthStateChanged`](/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state) listeners will trigger with the new authentication state of the user. The result from the `signInWithEmailLink` can also be used to retrieve information about the user that signed in

---

## Testing the email login link in the simulator

1. Have the app installed on the running simulator
2. Go through the flow that will send the magic link to the email
3. Go to your inbox and copy the link address
4. Open a terminal and paste the following code

```sh
xcrun simctl openurl booted {paste_the_link_here}
```

- This will start the app if it’s not running
- It will trigger the onLink hook (if you have a listener for it like above)

---

## References

- [Deep Linking In React Native Using Firebase Dynamic Links](https://www.codingular.com/2020/01/deep-linking-in-react-native-using-firebase-dynamic-links/#comments)
- [React Native Firebase - Dynamic Links](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage)
- [React Native Firebase - auth - signInWithEmailLink](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#isSignInWithEmailLink)
- [firebase.google.com - Passing State In Email Actions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions#configuring_firebase_dynamic_links)
- [firebase.google.com - Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link in JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this guide. I also had to create a dummy dynamic link in Firebase for the app to open after pressing the link in the email.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me too. Just a comment, for the buttons I think you forgot to pass in the email in the onPress props. Outside that, thanks for such a detailed process 

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for taking the time to put this together!

Comment: slight variation, you might need to pass the link in quotes sometimes

Comment: This is great. I don't know what the links are though. How do you know what to set them to? Could I just make anything up, or does it have to be an actual domain?

Comment: It depends which link are you referring to. If you don't want to use a custom domain for dynamic links you can input `{project}.page.link` as a domain. Otherwise you have to use your own domain and prove that you own it. The `url` in `actionCodeSettings` can be any (whitelisted) url, but people will be redirected there if they don't have your app installed or have clicked the "magic-link" from a desktop computer. And finally if it's the **Associated Domains** it should match the dynamic link domain you are using e.g.  `{project}.page.link` or the custom domain (that you own)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! You rock!

Comment: Is it mandatory to set dynamic links if I only want to send a user to a webpage with a sign in ?

Comment: If you just want to point someone to the sign in page it shouldn't be necessary to have dynamic links, you can just present the plain link for `https://your-app/login`

Comment: Thanks for the great guide! I was able to receive the email perfectly, however I am having some issues with the whitelisted dynamic link. It is getting blocked by firebase although I have gone into auth-->setting-->add domain and added several potential links there. I also added the deep link just in case that was causing the issue. I know it has been over a year since your last response, but do you have any insight on what might be going on?

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. You can inspect the link from the email (before clicking it) and add the domain in auth. Are dynamic links enabled for the project? Did you have the domain `{firebase-project}.page.link`  to the authorized domains?