# My firebase dynamic link is being blocked by firebase (firebase passwordless login)

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Hey everyone so I am following along with this [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564203/how-to-setup-sendsigninlinktoemail-from-firebase-in-react-native)  response to set up passwordless login with react native firebase. I was able to get through the first half of the process fine, however now that I am getting the actual dynamic link in my email response. I am getting redirected to a firebase page with the following error

" Invalid Dynamic Link - Blocked

We could not match param 'https://MY PROJECT NAME.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=*************MY API KEY************&mode=signIn&oobCode=*******NOT SURE WHAT THIS CODE IS***********&continueUrl=https://MYPROJECT.page.link/M3bd&lang=en' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project.

If you are the developer of this app, ensure that your Dynamic Links domain is correctly configured and that the path component of this URL is valid."

This is pretty obvious that I just need to whitelist a domain from this error, so I went to auth-->Setting--> add a domain and added several possible domains that I thought could be responsible for this. I added,

my working firebase dynamic link URL(https://MYPROJECT.page.link/M3bd) I tested it on mobile and desktop and both seem to be working perfectly

I copied and pasted the whole URL from the error I was getting

and I even pasted the fallback deep link that the dynamic link will route to if someone is on desktop(in my case it is just my company's website dashboard)

Even doing all this I am still getting the error, so I am a little confused on why this might be happening. Down below is my function that is sending these emails in the first place. I am not sure if this is helpful, but I figured it would be good to include. Thanks in advance!

```
 const sendSignInLink = async (emailInput: string) => {
        const actionCodeSettings = {
            handleCodeInApp: true,
            // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
            url: 'https://MYPROJECT.page.link/M3bd',
            iOS: {
                bundleId: BUNDLE_ID,
            },
            android: {
                packageName: BUNDLE_ID,
                installApp: true,
                minimumVersion: '12',
            },
        };
```